# How to install a network of four nodes in Substrate

Tags: substrate

i have tested Substrate and had some tutorials, now i want install a small network of four nodes.
The problem is that i have no tutorials and no idea how to installa four nodes in four different machines and connect them.

Have some tuts or could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen this? https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/start-a-private-network-with-substrate feel free to update you post if you have a more specific question

Comment: Hey @ShawnTabrizi, that's was i find it, tahnk you so much +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a tutorial on setting up a network of multiple Substrate chains in our Substrate Developer Hub:

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/simulate-network/